# Will windows 7 run smoothly on this machine?

Tags: windows-7

I would like to know if you think this machine will or will not run windows 7 without any problems.

Specs:
Intel Pentium 4 630
1.0GB Dual Channel DDR2 267MHz
512MB GeFOrce 8400GS

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of my computers running Win7 (x86) smoothly (and used to run Vista (x86) smoothly as-well) is a Pentium 4 2.1GHz CPU, 1.5GB DDR2 RAM, Geforce 5400 256mb graphics.

Of course it is not used for heavy-duty stuff, mostly for general purpose (e.g. internet, viewing and listening to media, some simple games etc').

The answer is [as always] depends on what you are planning to do with it.
For most things it will probably be OK.

Answer (score 0):

It is at the bottom of the x86 [requirements](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windows-7/get/system-requirements.aspx) and below the x64 requirements.

I would say that you could install the x86 version and use it, but it probably wouldn't be a great performer.

Comment: but do you think I would have a lot of crashes?

Comment: @nunos - You should only have crashes if something is wrong with your hardware or software configuration. Crashes are not normal if you are within the requirements.

Comment: more RAM would be nice